# Chrome extension global variable weirdness

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in the popup.js of a chrome extension.

```
var tt;
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true, windowType: 'normal' },
  function (tabs) {
      tt = 5;      
});
 document.getElementById('elm').textContent = tt;
```

But the weird thing is value of tt is undefined when accessed out side of the function, but it shows "5" if the  `document.getElementById('elm').textContent = tt;`  is put inside the function. So why is the variable value is not retained when the control exit the function ?

What am I doing wrong here ?

This code runs when the popup is shown. I.e. when the browser action's button is clicked and I simplified the code be readable. Actually I'm trying to get the current tab's id in to a variable. But nothing works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current tab and pass it to variable in a Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955408/get-current-tab-and-pass-it-to-variable-in-a-chrome-extension) (third result from a [Google search for "site:stackoverflow.com chrome.tabs.query asynchronous"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+chrome.tabs.query+asynchronous) and one of the two result from a [SO search for "\[google-chrome-extension\] +chrome.tabs.query + asynchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome-extension%5D+%2Bchrome.tabs.query+%2Basynchronous)).

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer, if anyone ran into this again, this is what happened.

The `chrome.tabs.query` is an async operation so the callback function was called a little bit later. But the   `document.getElementById('elm').textContent = tt;`  line was executed before the callback was called and it caused the issue. When debugging this did not happen as the stepping through the code delays the execution of that line.