# Google Chrome Extension Variable using sendMessage from Content Script to Background Page is Undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a basic Google Chrome Extension I am working on, and having a problem getting a value from localStorage.  I am using sendMessage in the content script to ask for the variable from the background page.  When I get the response, the variable is always "undefined", unless I put something like an alert() after the response...then the variable contains my value.  Can you help me to figure out why this is and how to do it correctly?  I have made the code for this post and it is below.  Thank you very much!

---

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "A test extension.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
 "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

---

### content.js

```
alert('content');

var color;

chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting:"color"},function(response){color = response.farewell;});

// alert('pause'); // uncommenting this line lets me get the value...why?

alert('content - ' + color);
```

---

### background.js

```
alert('background');

localStorage["color"] = "lightblue";

var color = localStorage["color"];

alert('background - ' + color);

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse)
{

if (request.greeting == "color") {sendResponse({farewell:color});}

});
```

---

Thank you very much for any help!  :)

Comment: See this answer to learn what's wrong with your code, and how to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11689804/938089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the response is in the callback function. When you have this:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting:"color"},function(response){color = response.farewell;});

alert('content - ' + color);
```

The browser executes sendMessage and then IMMEDIATELY goes ot the next line, the alert. The callback in sendMessage is fired *after*. The alert 'fixes' it because you are basically pausing the browser. If you want to use color as a variable, you can only use it inside the callback: function(response).

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you, Raymond, and Rob.