# How chrome.storage.local.get sets a value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
var css = "old";
storage.set({'css': 'new'});
storage.get('css', function(items) {
    if (items.css) {
        css = items.css;
        console.log(css);
    }
});
console.log(css);
```

I am trying to upgrade my chrome extension to fit the manifest version 2.
While I run the code above, I get the first console.log returns "new" and the second one returns "old".  How can I get two "new" if I want to set css to a new value?

Comment: Like most Chrome APIs, `chrome.storage.get`/`set` are **asynchronous**. I've written an explanation of this in easy terms, which can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11689804/938089).

Comment: Thank you for that answer.  That's a very good explanation .  However, I really want to ues 'css' outside the callback function.  Is there any way to to so?

Comment: No. You cannot turn an asynchronous function in a synchronous function without changing the flow of your application.

Answer (score 5):

I will explain why you are getting that behavior and how to fix.

This is your code:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
var css = "old";
storage.set({'css': 'new'});
storage.get('css', function(items) {
  if (items.css) {
    css = items.css;
    console.log(css);
  }
});
console.log(css);
```

First of all you should know that by design, most of javascript API (at least from browser) accesing I/O is asynchronic , this include the chrome.storage API because it access a DB/filesystem or something implying I/O operations

Second, the Javascript code combine both, synchronous and asynchronous code running, hence the confusion

Asynchronous code runs on JS EventLoop , always **after** your synchronous code (there is no threads on JS), so, in your code, 5 always will run **before** 6:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local; // 1
var css = "old"; // 2
storage.set({'css': 'new'}); // 3
storage.get('css', function(items) {
  // 6. this only will run AFTER this synchronous code returns
  if (items.css) {
    css = items.css;
    console.log(css);
  }
}); // 4
console.log(css); // 5. this always run before ANY callback
```

In fact there is chance of things running **before** 6 and **after** 5 (depending on how fast the I/O operation completes and invoke your callback)

**Now, the solution**

You need to do in the callback whatever you want to do with the retrieved info, this style of programming you can like it or not, but it is the JS way (soon as the code turns more complex and consume more I/O api you will be worried about callback hells and it can be addressed using Promises/Deferred, but that's another matter)

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local; // 1
// var css = "old"; // 2
storage.set({'css': 'new'}); // 3
storage.get('css', function(items) {
  // 5. this only will run AFTER this synchronous code returns
  if (items.css) {
    var css = items.css; // this variable belongs to this scope
    // do here whatever you need with the retrieved info
    // since it is CSS, maybe you want to create a new stylesheet of that (is only an example)
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerText = css;
    document.head.appendChild(style);
  }
}); // 4
// console.log(css); // can't access css here, is synchronous and it runs before the callback
```