# node.js global variable problematical

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know javascript very well. I can't define a global variable.

```
var data = 'empty';

connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme',function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err) throw err;
    data = rows;
});

console.log(data);
```

Normally, console need to return rows' data but It returns 'empty'. How can I query rows from inside of function? How can I define a global variable?

Comment: This is not a problem with global variable definition, but trying to use asynchronous methods in a synchronous way. That's not possible. I've written an analogy, perhaps it helps you with understanding it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11689804/938089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you `console.log` is outside the asynchronous code block. Basically what is happening is this:

1. `data` is set to `empty`;
2. `connection` issues a database request;
3. `console.log` fires ( `data` is `empty` at that point );
4. database response is received;
5. callback fires;
6. `data` is set to `rows`.

So in order to get what you want simply put `console.log` statement inside an asynchronous block code:

```
var data = 'empty';

connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme',function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err) throw err;
    data = rows;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: how would u return the value?

Comment: You can't. That's not how you do asynchronous programming.