# xml onreadystatechange issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, readystate

I'm trying to work my way out with `XMLHttpRequest`, but I've run into an issue:

```
function x(url, callback) { //edited

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) {
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText;) //edited
        } else {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<div class="error">Ups, an error ocurred! Server response: <span>'+xmlHttp.responseText+'</span></div>';
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function y()
{
    var url = base_url + '?asa=test';
    x(url, function (response) { //edited
       console.log(response);
    });
}
```

But my problem is the `if readyState == 4`. The output of the `console.log` is always undefined and never enters the `if`, only `else` and that's because the first time the `if` is executed, `readyState` has the value of `1`.

So, any way to work around that issue because it's making me crazy, I've tried everything I could think of for now.

### UPDATE

The code's format, it's what I last tried because before I had it separated, in variables and all kinds of things that I tried to work around the issue

Btw, a `console.log(xmlHttp.readyState)` inside `onreadystatechange`'s function, will output one by one: 1, 2, 3 and 4

Comment: is get_url supposed to be x?

Comment: It's ***Asynchronous*** XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Alex , yes... i just fixed the code

Comment: Have a look at [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11689804/1048572), which explains your problem and offers a solution

Comment: @bergi, the same problem happens even if I set it to synchronous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As bergi said, the request is asynchronous. This means x returns immediately, and xmlHttp.onreadystatechange is called **later**. If you need to do something with the response from within y, pass it as a callback so x can call it when the time is right:

```
function x( callback )
{
    if( pseudocode: request is ok )
    {
        callback( response );
    }
}

function y()
{
    x( url, function( response )
    {
        // do something with the response.
    } );
}
```

**UPDATE**

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange is called with readyState 1, 2, and 3 before 4.

```
if( state === 4 )
{
    if( statuscode === 200 )
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        // failure
    }
}
/*else
{
    ignore states 1, 2 and 3
}*/
```

Comment: so far so great, but I still can't figure it out why the hell the `else` gets executed, **synchronous** or **Asynchronous** . I've updated my code

Comment: I've updated my answer. Not sure if that is the stack overflow way of doing it though - should I have started a new answer?

Comment: @Alex you responded my question, that's what you did... the separate `if` solution I had already tried it... my problem was with it mixed... but thanks anyway