# window.open after getting tabid in chrome extension not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs, window.open

I am trying to open a new tab after getting the current tabid so that I can pass
a message from the newly opened tab to the previous one,
I am doing this:

**myscr.js:**

```
var myvar = 0;
chrome.tabs.query({
  currentWindow: true,
  active: true
}, function (tabs) {
  console.log(tabs[0]);
  myvar = tabs[0].id;
  //console.log(myvar);
});
var string_url = "getfilehandler.html/?" + "tabid=" + myvar;
window.open(string_url);
```

**manifest.json:**

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus", "fileBrowserHandler"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["file:///home/user/Desktop/itproject/test.html"],
    "js": ["myscr.js"]
  }
],
```

My problem is when I am opening the file `test.html` the browser nothing seems to be 
happening!

the new window is opened when I am using just `window.open(...)` in `myscr.js`. I'm not really sure why it is happening! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

changes:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,                              // Select active tabs
    windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT // In the current window
}, function(array_of_Tabs) {
    // Since there can only be one active tab in one active window, 
    //  the array has only one element
    var tab = array_of_Tabs[0];
    // Example:
    var url = tab.url;
console.log(url);
    // ... do something with url variable
});
```

Comment: The `chrome.tabs` API is not available to content scripts. Your code has to be moved to a background page if you really want to use the tabId. If you want to continue with using the tabId, make sure that you understand that the `chrome.tabs.query` method is asynchronous, as explained in [After calling chrome.tabs.query, the results are not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688171/after-calling-chrome-tabs-query-the-results-are-not-available/11689804#11689804).

Comment: That code is quite unreadable. Consider editing your question to add the code. Since no-one has posted an answer yet, you can as well edit the existing question because it won't invalidate (non-existing) answers.

Comment: @RobW: I have updated the changes in the question.
I guess it's your code itself!
managed to find it on some other thread!

Comment: Did you already move the code to the [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)? Earlier I already said that the `chrome.tabs` API is unavailable to content scripts. You can trigger the code via the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event, or send a message from the content script using the [message passing API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: oh! sorry I did not notice that (my bad)!!
I want to modify the values of textfields of a specific webpage,
so I have to stick with content scripts!
do you know any other method where I can communicate between the tabs?

Comment: Yes, check out the documentation I linked in my previous comment.