# Chrome Extension: query tabs async

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I have two variables being set to the "return value" of functions, these functions are to get the URL of a tab, and a reference to the actual tab object, and store them in variables. I have some code:

```
function init(){
    var url = getUrl();
    var tab = getTab();
}

function getUrl(){
    var tablink;
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},function(tabs){
        tablink = tabs[0].url;
        return tablink;
    });

}

function getTab(){
    var tab;
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},function(tabs){
        tab = tabs[0];
    });
    return tab;
}
```

Why is it that, URL is undefined, though I'm returning the URL from within the callback function, yet when I return tab from outside of the callback, it returns fine, as though this were a synchronous call. I have a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijPbp.png) of this phenomenon in the debugger. I'm trying my best to learn how to deal with the asynchronous methods in chrome, but this is very confusing. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [After calling chrome.tabs.query, the results are not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688171/after-calling-chrome-tabs-query-the-results-are-not-available)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already said the `chrome.tabs.query` function is asynchronous. Because of this, you cannot rely on `return`, instead you have to use callbacks. The documentation for Chrome extension explains it quite well: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#sync-example

So in your case, something like this might work (depends on what you want to later with it).

```
var url, tab;
function init(){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},function(tabs){
       url = tabs[0].url;
       tab = tabs[0];
       //Now that we have the data we can proceed and do something with it
       processTab();
    });
}

function processTab(){
    // Use url & tab as you like
    console.log(url);
    console.log(tab);
}
```

Comment: I really just want a way to save the tab as a variable. I can't figure out a way to access the results of an asynchronous function after the function has executed.

Comment: I adjusted my answer a bit, so that the results are now stored in variables instead of passing them directly. But as this runs async, you need to use and call an additional function for further using the data (that's the callback).