# Function doesn't define variable correctly

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have the following code:

```
var first="";
var run=function(){

    first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

    if(first.substring(0,6)==="http://"){
       first=first.substring(7,first.length-1);
    }

    if (first.substring(0, 1) !== " " &&
        first !== "unrequired" && 
        first.substring(0, 7) !== "http://" &&
        first.substring(0, 8) !== "https://" && 
        first !== undefined && 
        first !== "" && 
        first.substring(0, 9) !== "chrome://" && 
        first.substring(0, 12) !== "view-source:" && 
        first.substring(0, 8) !== "file:///") {
      first="http://"+first;
    }

    if(first===""||first==="unrequired"){
       first=undefined;
    }
    if (first.substring(0,1)===" "){
       first="https://www.google.com/search?q=" + first.substring(1,first.length);
    }
    chrome.tabs.create({url:first})
};
setInterval(run,1);
```

But the chrome.tabs.create only runs if I move it outside the function and don't run the function. Clearly the function does something to the variable, but what? I even used an alert that told me something was wrong

Comment: ps I can't look at inspect element

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, but I can help you help yourself with some styling/formatting suggestions: use proper indentation in your code so you and other people can read it properly; don't use global variables - since anyone or anything can write in that variable, you never know what will happen to it; give your functions and variables more suggestive names: first - first what? run - run what? It will make things easier - for you in the first place and for everybody else reading/working with your code :)

Comment: `first.substring(0,6)` can never be `"http://"`. ["indexEnd ...specifies the offset into the string of the first character not to include in the returned substring."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). Maybe not very clear, but the `first[6]` is not included to the return value.

Comment: As a sidenote, since you're only using the substrings to check if 'first' contains a specific word, indexOf wil probably suffice. Then you can also wrap it all into a switch statement to have a bit cleaner structure.

Comment: You might have problems accessing the variable because your in an async call. Allthough I don't know why this is happening. Seems there are more threads on this subject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028950/chrome-extension-query-tabs-async

Comment: I'm also going to guess that chrome might actually block this for a good reason since what you are trying to do would in time open an infinite number of tabs. Which does not feel all that secure.