# why i cannot add breakpoint to code line such as chrome.tabs.query?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i can break before chrome.tabs.query lines:

[image]

stop at line 7

[image]

F10 and run to line 9

[image]

F10 and

**it does not stop at line 14, it goes directly to line 20, why the break point not works?**

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688171/after-calling-chrome-tabs-query-the-results-are-not-available

Comment: It's not merely related, it's a 90% duplicate.

Comment: that thread has nothing to do with break point:(

Comment: Read. That. Answer. The callback is asynchronous and not going to be executed until the document ready function exits.