# Getting links from google search returns only google links. Page not finished loading it seems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on this chrome extension that will highlight links in a google search if it is already open in another tab. Currently, I can get the tabs that are already open from the background.js to the content.js, however, getting the links from a google search does not work very well. Here are my 3 scripts (they might be a little funny currently since I have been working on trying to fix the problem.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Tab Highlighter",
"description": "Highlight links in a Google Search if they are already open in another tab",
"version": "1.0",
"content_scripts":[
{
    "matches": [ "http://www.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*" ],
    "js": [ "content.js" ]
}
],
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions":[ "tabs" ]
}
```

**background.js** *I don't think it has to do with this*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if(request.data === "getTabs"){
var fourmTabs = new Array();
chrome.tabs.query({}, 
        function(t) {
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            console.log("There are ", links.length , " links on the page.");
            for(var k = 0; k < links.length; k++) {
                console.log(links[k].innerHTML);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                var temp = t[i].url;
                var fin = temp.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
                if(fin.substr(-1) == '/') {
                    fin = fin.substr(0, fin.length - 1);
                }
                fourmTabs[i] = fin;
            }
            // Moved code inside the callback handler
            for (var i = 0; i < fourmTabs.length; i++) {
                if (fourmTabs[i] != null) {
                    //console.log(fourmTabs[i]);
                    }
                else {
                    console.log("??" + i);
                }
            }
            if(!fourmTabs) {
                console.log("Tabs could not be generated!!");
            }
            else {
                for(i = 0; i < fourmTabs.length; i++) {
                    console.log("fourmtabs is here: ", fourmTabs[i]);
                }
            }
            //setTimeout(function(){a},4000);
            sendResponse({data: fourmTabs});
        }
    );
    //sendResponse({});
    return true;
}
});
```

**content.js**

```
window.addEventListener ("load", 
function() {
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: "getTabs"}, function(response) {
console.log("Scanning page and comparing open tabs.");
var tabs = response.data;
if(!tabs) {
    console.log("No Tabs could be found!! Most likely an error.");
}
else {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    if(links.length == 0) {
        console.log('query found nothing.');
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i].href.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
        if(link.substr(-1) == '/') {
            link = link.substr(0, link.length - 1);
        }
        console.log("found link: ", link);
        var real_href = links[i];
        //console.log("real_href: ", real_href);
        if(link) {
            for(var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
                if(link == tabs[j]) {
                    console.log("duplicate found: ", link);
                    console.log("real_href dup: ", real_href);
                    real_href.style.background = "#00FFFB";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("End comparing.");

}
});
});
```

Currently it will get all of the google anchor tags, however not the actual search tags. I have tried multiple changes to content.js to attempt to get them, however the success seems very random almost. I think it is mainly based on how the page is loaded. I thought that having the `window.addEventListener` at the beginning would wait until the page's content was completely loaded before calling the background.js and then getting the page's links. **I did have ran_at option in content_scripts of the manifest set to document_end but it did not help any, therefore i removed it, thinking the window.addEventListener would take over.

Most all links are in `<h3>` tags and if I query for those the result comes back empty. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information. [This is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622430/pass-array-variable-from-background-js-to-content-js) to a previous question I asked that got answered, however it was more on sending a message from background.js to content.js.

I attempted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917047/how-to-get-a-content-script-to-load-after-a-pages-javascript-has-executed) for my question, but as I said, it didn't seem to help.

Comment: In your question above you mention trying out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917047/how-to-get-a-content-script-to-load-after-a-pages-javascript-has-executed . Unfortunately, that's not an answer - its a question. Which of its answers have you tried?

Comment: @FuzzyAmi I tried the marked answer to that question. Specifically, calling the `window.addEventListener("load", function(){}` at the beginning to try to wait for all the contents from the search query to show up so content.js would have access to everything on the screen.

Comment: I see. That same answer offers another option: to try and poll until the page is fully formed. You could also just wait a fixed amount of time - like a second. it'll work, but its ugly.

Comment: @FuzzyAmi Setting a timeout seems to work, where the function call is the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` part, and the timeout is 1 second. It took a while to get this specific time, and it is a little finicky. I may try the other solution, I was just really baffled by why the window onload function was not working. I think that Google has certain part's of the DOM loaded automatically (like they "hardcoded" certain parts such as the different searches, and all of their other stuff). I might try the other answer, it just didn't make sense the first 5 times I read it haha.