# Accessing the information from chrome.tabs.query outside of the scope of the callback function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the following snippet the alert tells me that "taburl" is undefined. Is there any way of accessing the query result outside of the callback function?

```
  var taburl;
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    taburl = tabs[0].url;
  });
  alert(taburl);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way that you are approaching this problem is incorrect because `chrome.tabs.query` is an **asynchronous method**. [Read this excellent answer for an explanation of what that entails, as well as a possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689804/845680)

**EDIT:**

Depending on how your project is structured, the simplest solution is to wrap the logic that requires the tab info in a function. Then you can invoke that function from within the `chrome.tabs.query` callback and pass the tab info in. For example:

```
var alertTab = function(tab) { alert(tab); }
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
  alertTab(tabs[0].url);
});
```

This is a very naive/dangerous approach and will only work if you wrap all of the *synchronous* code dependent on the tab info in that (or other) functions. There are many better approaches that are less bug prone... check out the promise pattern, for example.

Comment: I edited in a basic example to show one way to access that info outside of the callback. (Better than using `setTimeout` :P, but there are other better solutions as well - it all depends on how your code is structured)