# Chrome extension dialouge box in center of browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm fairly new to Chrome Extension development, and I'm wondering is there any way I can open the dialogue box appear in the center of the browser (horizontally and vertically) when I click on the extension icon.

I'm not able to find any extension which does this, so asking here.

Comment: You mean the dialogue box opened after clicking `Add to chrome` button?

Comment: One method is to [open a new small window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865325), the other one is to send a message to the content script which will show a DOM element (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension)).

Comment: @random no. I mean after the extension is installed, I need to open the extension in the centre when I click on the icon. Usually, the box appears on the left side of the screen where the extension icon is.