# Chrome extension not finding current tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

In my code, I want to check if on the page you are on, if certain requirements are met with the url, do something

It is saying it cannot get the toLowerCase of undefined

this is my code, thanks

Also, I do have tab permissions in the manifest
This file runs in the background, I want it to execute for every page you open

```
var names = ['hunter5deer', 'pielovingcat', '199MS', 'harrdy']
$(function() {
    for (i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
        var currentPage;
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
            currentPage = tab.url;
        });
        var page;
        if (currentPage.toLowerCase().indexOf("item?id=") > -1) {
            page = 'seller';
            name(page, names[i]);

        }
        else if (currentPage.toLowerCase().indexOf("showpost.aspx?postid=") > -1) {
            page = 'forum';
            name(page, names[i]);
        }
        else if (currentPage.toLowerCase().indexOf("user.aspx?") > -1) {
            page = 'profile'
            name(page, names[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11688171/2336725

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected` executes asynchronously so the if statement was running before `currentPage` was set. Move the if statement inside the callback.

```
var names = ['hunter5deer', 'pielovingcat', '199MS', 'harrdy']
$(function() {
    for (i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
            var currentPage = tab.url;
            var page;
            if (currentPage.toLowerCase().indexOf("item?id=") > -1) {
                page = 'seller';
                name(page, names[i]);

            }
            else if (currentPage.toLowerCase().indexOf("showpost.aspx?postid=") > -1) {
                page = 'forum';
                name(page, names[i]);
            }
            else if (currentPage.toLowerCase().indexOf("user.aspx?") > -1) {
                page = 'profile'
                name(page, names[i]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```