# how can i pass variable to chrome.storage.sync.get()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i want to pass value to chrome.storage.sync.get() function.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('privateKey', function(data, e) {
  if (data.privateKey) {
    var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
    decrypt.setPrivateKey(data.privateKey);
    var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(e.detail.encryptedVal)
    alert(uncrypted);
  } else {
    alert("key is not set");
  }
 });
```

but e.detail.encryptedVal is showing me as undefined.

Comment: I do not understand your question. `get` callback should have only one parameter ( `data` ) and in it stored retrieved object. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: because for decryption i need it encrypted value with private key as well , although i have also separate the logic to get sync storage value but it return nothing..

Comment: So let me get this straight: You'd like if you could pass `e` to the `get` callback in order to decrypt the value?

Comment: yes, if you have any other solution please suggest i am new to js.

Comment: Writing an in-depth answer.

Answer (score 2):

The callback of `.get()` [expects exactly 1 parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-get-callback).

By passing a function that takes 2 parameters (i.e. `function(data, e) {...}`), you do the following:

1. The function is called with one parameter. It is assigned to a callback-local variable `data`.
2. The second parameter stays undefined. It is assigned to a callback-local variable `e`.
3. If there was a variable `e` in the outer scope, it is no longer accessible.

I assume the part 3 is exactly your problem. You *had* a variable `e` in the scope where you called `.get()`, but you made it inaccessible.

Generally, due to the concept called [*closures*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), you don't actually need to pass `e` inside the scope - you just *use* the variable from the outer scope, and it will be retained in memory until the function executes. Think of it as a "locally global" variable, if that makes any sense. If it doesn't, there are [better explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

With that in mind:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('privateKey', function(data) { // just don't mention e here
  /* ... */
    // Just use e inside if it comes from outer scope
    var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(e.detail.encryptedVal);
  /* ... */
});
```

Better yet, let's make that into a function:

```
function decryptValue(value, callback) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get('privateKey', function(data) {
    var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
    decrypt.setPrivateKey(data.privateKey);
    var decrypted = decrypt.decrypt(value);
    callback(decrypted);
  }
}

/* ... */
decryptValue(e.detail.encryptedVal, function(decrypted) {
  // Do something
});
/* ... */
```

Note that `callback` variable? While you can use `decrypted` inside the callback of `.get()`, due to the fact it's asynchronous you can't use it outside. There is a [very good overview of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688171/after-calling-chrome-tabs-query-the-results-are-not-available), and [another one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). Basically, `.get()` is asynchronous so you HAVE to use a callback.

```
/* ... */
decryptValue(e.detail.encryptedVal, function(decrypted) {
  // Do something with decrypted
});
// Here, decrypted is not yet computed
/* ... */
```

Most of Chrome API is asynchronous. I would recommend to read [You Don't Know JS book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance) on the topic.

Comment: thanks your answers works for me but i have only problem document.addEventListener("encrypt", function(e) { var encryptedVal = e.detail.encryptedVal; console.info("encrypted value is: ", e.detail.encryptedVal); decrypt(encryptedVal); }); without console.info value is not passess to decrypt function

Comment: How do you know that? You need a callback to do anything with the value.

Comment: i have follow your way and it works but in listener without console.info(e.detail.encryptedVal) value is neither showing nor send to decrypt function.

Comment: How do you know it's not sent? `decryptValue(something)` on itself will not show anything. You need to pass a second argument (callback) to use the decrypted value (for example, to show it).

Answer (score 1):

So, from the comments bellow, I suppose you'd like to pass the value to `get` callback in order to user it in the callback. Unfortunately, this can't be done the way you want it to be done. But, what you can do is write a `decrypt` function that will take the `encryptedVal` as an argument, and simply use it

```
function decrypt(encryptedVal) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('privateKey', function (data) {
        if (data.privateKey) {
            var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
            decrypt.setPrivateKey(data.privateKey);
            var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(encryptedVal)
                alert(uncrypted);
        } else {
            alert("key is not set");
        }
    });
}
```

Do note that this function uses asynchronous code and you may not `return` from it as you'd expect.

Comment: Well, ninja'd by seconds.

Comment: thanks your answer works for me but i have only problem 
document.addEventListener("encrypt", function(e) {
    var encryptedVal = e.detail.encryptedVal;
    console.info("encrypted value is: ", e.detail.encryptedVal);
    decrypt(encryptedVal);
  }); 
without console.info value is not passess to decrypt function