# How to get the URL starting the connection in a Chrome add-on

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a plugin in Chrome that have to selectively block communications. For example, block all the connections to third parties when I'm in `cnn.com`, or block the cookies of Facebook when I'm not in Facebook (to avoid Facebook tracking).

I'm able to intercept the traffic using:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    analyzeRequests, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['blocking']
);

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    analyzeHeaders, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);
```

Then, inside the `analyzeRequests` and `analyzeHeaders` functions I obtain the URL of the request, but I cannot get the URL of the tab initiating the connection because the `tabs.get` method is asynchronous. To avoid this problem I keep a hashtable with the URL of every tab as shown here: [Get current tab and pass it to variable in a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955408/get-current-tab-and-pass-it-to-variable-in-a-chrome-extension)

That way I can have the URL of the request (`url_req`) and the URL of the tab originating the request (`url_main`).

Nevertheless, that solution has a big problem: the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is triggered late, after the first connections are done, and that causes:

- When the user goes to a new page on purpose (clicking on a link or typing a new URL in the address bar) for me the `url_main` is still the URL of the previous web. So, in the example of blocking third parties in `cnn.com`, I would block any try to go to other page.
- For the first request originated in the new URL, the add-on still thinks the user is in the previous page. It will cause the program to apply the wrong policies. In the example of Facebook, it will block the cookies of Facebook in the first connection to Facebook, so, Facebook will redirect the user to the login page.
- If the connection is initiated inside an iframe (or similar) it will also fail to apply the rules. Since I can get the URL of the main page, but not the one of the iframe. (However, this problem is not really important).

I don't know if there is a way to know, for example, the text written in the address bar, or to monitorize (in a synchronous way) when the user has followed a link or typed a new URL in the address bar.

Comment: I don't understand why `url_main is still the url of the previous web` because it should be caught with `tabUrlsHashtable[details.tabId] !== details.url && details.type == 'main_frame'`. I'd like to see more code or maybe the entire extension.

Comment: Thanks for your comments pointing out to the details.type == "main_frame". Now I added this line to my analyzeRequest function it works:
    if (details.type === "main_frame"){
        console.log("Updating URL to " + details.url);
        tabIdToURL[details.tabId] = details.url;
    }

Comment: @user1753235, Actual answers/solutions should be posted as Answers, not edited into the question. It is a good idea to wait a bit to see if a user who posted a comment which has solved your problem posts an answer, if they do not do so after a reasonable period of time (actual amount of time is indeterminate), then you should post the answer/solution as an answer with a mention of the user who provided the information (as mentioned in your edit to your question). Self answered questions are encouraged.

Comment: However, I would still down-vote without more information provided by you. As it is, the question requires the person answering to **guess** at the fact that your handlers were not checking the `details.type`. A question is *never* complete if it requires the person answering to *guess* at what the problem is. So, please [edit] your question to include enough of your handler(s) to show that you are not checking `details.type`. Please leave a comment for me (include `@Makyen` in the comment) after you [edit] this information into your question so I can remove my down-vote (& probably up-vote).

Answer (score 0):

**The following was edited into the question by user1753235 as an answer  based on comments by wOxxOm:**

As indicated by wOxxOm, if the user visits the page on purpose, the first request is marked as 'main_frame'. So, adding the following code solve the problem with the asynchronous hastable:

```
if (details.type === "main_frame"){
    tabIdToURL[details.tabId] = details.url;
}
```